# Add increasing number for each group in column of Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 2 columns "Id" and "category". For each category, I want to label encode the column "Id", so the expected outcome will be the column "Enc_id" like this

```
Id   Category    Enc_id
a1       A         0
a2       A         1
b1       B         0 
c1       C         0
c2       C         1
a3       A         2
b2       B         1
b3       B         2 
b4       B         3 
b4       B         3
b3       B         2
```

Here, the Id may not be unique, so that there may be duplicated rows. I thought of creating a window to `partitionBy(category)`, then apply the label encoding (`StringIndexer`) over this window but it didn't work. Any hint, please?

Comment: is, the column id , unique?

Comment: @Raghu: it may or may not be. I've edited the questions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `window` function with `substring` function with and calculate the `rank`

```
val window = Window.partitionBy($"Category", substring($"Id", 1,1)).orderBy("Id")

df.withColumn("Enc_id", rank().over(window) - 1) // -1 to start the rank from 0
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+------+
|Id |Category|Enc_id|
+---+--------+------+
|a1 |A       |0     |
|a2 |A       |1     |
|a3 |A       |2     |
|c1 |C       |0     |
|c2 |C       |1     |
|b1 |B       |0     |
|b2 |B       |1     |
|b3 |B       |2     |
|b4 |B       |3     |
+---+--------+------+
```

**Update1:**
for the updated case with duplicate id

```
df1.groupBy("Id", "Category")
  .agg(collect_list("Category") as "list_category")
  .withColumn("Enc_id", rank().over(window) - 1)
  .withColumn("Category", explode($"list_category"))
  .drop("list_category")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+------+
|Id |Category|Enc_id|
+---+--------+------+
|a1 |A       |0     |
|a2 |A       |1     |
|a3 |A       |2     |
|c1 |C       |0     |
|c2 |C       |1     |
|b1 |B       |0     |
|b2 |B       |1     |
|b3 |B       |2     |
|b3 |B       |2     |
|b4 |B       |3     |
|b4 |B       |3     |
+---+--------+------+
```

Comment: that's interesting. Does it also work if the Id is not unique? I mean there may be duplicated rows.

Comment: what should happen when row is duplicated? It depends on what you want

Comment: I've just edited the example in the question by adding 2 new lines at the end of the dataframe. The outputs should be the same as if you apply StringIndexer.

Comment: For the updated case you need to groupBy first and apply window function and again explode the aggregation. check the updates

Comment: thanks! Just another question, if I want to do something like: collect_list("Category").sliding(2,1), what is the correct syntax should be? Because I see that collect_list("Category") is an ArrayType(String) object, not a List.